# how to use this IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

I had modified this as Storage File `isoStore=StorageFile.________________();` but I can't find a method like GetUserStoreForApplication in Windows Phone 8.1. How to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the local storage folder with ApplicationData.LocalFolder or the roaming folder with ApplicationData.RoamingFolder.

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
```

See [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime (Windows Runtime apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464917.aspx) for more info on using application data and settings.